# Does this circuit detect frequency or magnetic field?

Tags: ac, dc, tester

I have built this circuit but the LED lights even when I move it near DC not only AC.

Does it detect the frequency or the magnetic field?

[image]

Comment: Magnetic fields that don't change don't affect electric currents.

Comment: if it detects the frequency why does the led lights when move it on DC? even the pen that they sell lights when u move it on DC, the 3xbc547 transistors work here as an ampilifier but i don't know why does it light on DC too not only AC as the diagram says

Comment: If you hold it still near a DC source what happens?

Comment: The led emits light that's why i don't know how does it work, the diagram says that it is AC only detector not DC too

Comment: The DC output may slightly be live with a large output impedance, like is usual with power supplies that aren’t earthed. So as you get close with the NVC detector due to capacitive coupling some current flows thus triggering it.

Comment: Makes me ask how clean that "DC" source is. I'll bet it isn't pure DC but has some AC noise on it. Try your probe near a battery in the middle of a field well away from power lines...

Comment: Put it near another 9V battery. Hold it still.

Comment: What kind of DC thing did you test it on?

Comment: the 9 V battery would need to have a load attached, like a lightbulb, otherwise you would not have to hold still

Comment: Assuming the BJT gains are around 200 I would guess that you need about 1 nA to turn on the LED (\$\approx {1 \over 200^3} {7.8 \over 1k}\$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

> *I have built this circuit but the LED lights even when I move it near
> DC not only AC*

It doesn't surprise me - the copper wire spiral and your hand are integral to make this work - if your hand is picking up AC electrical fields then the DC circuit is acting like a ground to the AC and enough AC voltage will appear across the base-emitter of the left transistor to operate it.

> *Does it detect the frequency or the magnetic field?*

It detects an AC electric field and a higher frequency will be more effective up to a certain point.

Answer (score 2):

With those three BC547 transistors arranged as they are, that circuit will probably do a pretty good imitation of an [electrometer.](http://amasci.com/emotor/chargdet.html)

A simple electrometer looks like this:

[image]

<sub>From the above linked web page.</sub>

It reacts to electric fields.  It can "see" batteries that are just standing there doing nothing.

They can also detect static charges, like an electrostatically charged wool sweater or blanket - or cat.

Being made of bipolar junction transistors (BJT) rather than a junction gate field effect transistor (JFET,) yours probabaly won't be as sensitive as the circuit above made from a JFET.

Your circuit is reacting to the electric fields, not specifically to AC.

Answer (score 1):

If you bring this detector near a perfect DC source, but your hand is not being held perfectly steady, you are in effect creating an "AC" voltage.   As you move closer & further from the DC electric field, the strength of the field changes, which is basically the same effect as if  you were near an actual 'AC' source